# Having trouble installing gcc in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, gcc, anaconda

I've tried to install gcc on anaconda but keep getting this errror:

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
> gcc

I've tried installing it with the following two commands:

- conda install -c conda-forge gcc
- conda install gcc

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is not working? I'm using windows Server 2016.

Thanks!

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: I'm on Windows Server 2016

Comment: You probably want this instead then: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/m2w64-gcc.
The `gcc` packages are mostly for linux and macOS. When it comes to Windows, it's a bit different as Microsoft has its own compiler and he environment is different to Unix-like OSes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Windows, you probably want to install [`m2w64-gcc`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/m2w64-gcc) instead.

The `gcc` packages are mostly for Linux and macOS. When it comes to Windows, it's a bit different as Microsoft has its own compiler and the environment is different to Unix-like OSes. Hence the different package.

Comment: I'm also having trouble installing facebook prophet: 'conda install -c conda-forge prophet'. Do you know another command that could help install it?

Comment: Not sure, it seems that there is an older version called `fbprophet` which may be worth trying.